# If $P$ is irreducible, then $I - P +A$ is invertible

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, matrix-equations, markov-process

Let $S = \{1, \dots, n\}$ be a space os states. $P$ irreducible means that $S$ has only one class. Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be a $n \times n$ matrix, where $a_{ij} = 1$, for all $i, j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and let $a = (1, \dots, 1)$.

Then $\pi$ is an invariant vector for $P$ if, and only if, $\pi (I - P +A) = a$ and if $P$ is irreducible, then $I - P +A$ is invertible.

If $\pi$ is invariant, $\pi P = \pi$. Then $\pi(I - P + A) = \pi - \pi + \pi A = \pi A = a$, as $\pi$ is a probability vector and $A$ is a matrix where all entries are equal to $1$.

Conversely, if $\pi (I - P + A) = a$, we have that $\pi - \pi P + a = a$. Thus, $\pi = \pi P$.

I am having some trouble to conclude that if $P$ is irreducible, then $I - P + A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is a column vector such that $(I-P+A)x=0$. You need to show that $x$ is the zero vector. You have  $x-Px+c\cdot a^t=0$, where $c:=\sum_i x_i$, and the superscript ${}^t$ denotes transpose. Pre-multiply repeatedly by $P$; after a little algebra you see that $x-P^n x+nc\cdot a^t=0$ for $n=2,3,\ldots$. Rearrange this to $nc\cdot a^t = P^n x-x$, and ask yourself what happens as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Does this implies that $x$ is zero vector ? It seems to me that this implies only $c=0$ but not $x=0$ ?

Comment: From $c=0$ you then get that $x=\lim_n P^n x$. But $P^n$ converges to a matrix with each row equal to $\pi$.  Thus $x=(\sum_i\pi_i x_i) a^t$, which means that the entries of $x$ are all the same. Because $c=0$, these entries are all $0$, so $x=0$.

Comment: I don't understand why for any $n\ge 1$ : $x - Px + c\cdot a^t =0 \implies x - P^nx + nc\cdot a^t =0 $ . I obtain this instead $x - Px + c\cdot a^t =0 \iff P^{n-1}x - P^nx + cP^{n-1} a^t =0 
\iff P^{n-1}x - P^nx + c\cdot a^t =0 \implies c\cdot a^t =0 \;(when \;n\to \infty) $ . Since $x\in ker(I-P+A)$ it is independent of $n$ , so $c\cdot a^t =0$ for all $n$ . Hence 
$x - Px + c\cdot a^t =0  \implies  (I-P) x =0 $ , but I cannot conclude $x=0$  .

Comment: From $x-Px+c\cdot a^t=0$ you get 
$P^{k-1}x-P^k x+c\cdot a^t=0$ for each $k\ge 1$. Add over $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ to get (by telescoping) $x-P^nx+nc\cdot a^t=0$.

This gives $P^nx =x$ for all $n\ge 1$. Irreducibility now implies that $x$ is a constant vector.